# how to assign multipul controller within a body

Tags: angularjs

How can i assign multiple controller within a body

**Html**

```
<script src="../MyApp.js"></script>
<script src="HomeCaller.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrls">{{secc}}</div>
    <div ng-controller="HomeCtrls">{{jan}}</div>
</body>
```

**MyApp.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
    app.controller('AppCtrls', function ($scope) {
        $scope.secc = "Hello Angular"
    })
})();
```

**HomeCaller.js**

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('HomeCtrls', function ($scope) {
    $scope.jan="Hello Jan"
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `[]` from the `module` call so you do not try to re-create it. This will retrieve the existing `MyApp` module.

**HomeCaller.js**

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('HomeCtrls', function ($scope) {
    $scope.jan="Hello Jan"
})
```